# Laravel 5 Dynamic Response

Tags: json, laravel, overriding, response

So I have 2 Models,
Cruiseship, with an Id, name, description, etc.
Then a Cruiseoverride that has a description which is supposed to be a custom replacement for the one on the Cruiseship model.

So my question is when querying the model and submitting a response to JSON, I want to be able to get the override and add it to the cruiseship response in place of the cruiseships description when a certain variable has been set. (for example $brand_id)

Currently I have this as a concept but Im not confident I will be doing it correctly.

```
public function getShip($id, $brand = false)
{
    if($brand) {
        $cruiseship = Cruiseship::where('status', '=', 1)
        ->where('id', '=', $id)
        ->get('id', 'name', 'slug');
        $override = Cruiseoverride::where('status', '=', 1)
        ->where('overridable_id', '=', $cruiseship->recno)
        ->where('overridable_type', '=', 'Ship')
        ->where('brand_id', '=', $brand)
        ->get('description');
    } else {
        $cruiseship = Cruiseship::where('status', '=', 1)
        ->where('id', '=', $id)
        ->get();
    }
    return response()->json($cruiseship);
}
```

Comment: Do I get it right, that in case you have a $brand variable - override description should be used instead of original description?

Comment: Please add more information, what are you trying to do and why? 

Looks to me like you only need one model "Cruiseship" and "Cruiseoverride" is an unneeded duplicate, but we need more info to be sure.